# Unix ,cron and MAILTO

Tags: cron, mailto

looking at possibility of configuring MAILTO , such that we have few crons mailing to one email id and others to a different email id.

will the following work ?

```
MAILTO="email1@"
SHELL=/bin/zsh
0,30 * * * * <cron job>
0 1 * * *  shashi zsh -c "export MAILTO='email2@';find /home/y/logs/ -daystart -type f -ctime +7 -print -exec rm -rf {} \;"
```

am expecting with this first cron job would mail to by default 'email1@' , while the second cron entry would mail to 'email2@' as we have overridden MAILTO.

Comment: Where are you writing this? In crontab? If so, you do not have to put the `crontab` text, just `* * * * * /interpreter/path /script/path`

Comment: thanks fedorqui , have edited the code.shall pilot and see if it works this way.

Comment: It is better if you store all this information in the script and then you just use crontab for executing it: `* * * * * /interpreter/path /script/path/sc.sh`, and sc.sh contains all the export, find, etc

Comment: Hmm I just tried the following
MAILTO="email1@"
SHELL="/bin/zsh"
* * * * * root zsh -c "export MAILTO='dev-mail-list@';echo \"Trial, please ignore\""\";
still see email onto email1@ , rather than 'dev-mail-list@' ?

Comment: No, no, crontab does not work like that, `root` is wrong in there. `* * * * * zsh /script/path/sc.sh` and then `sc.sh` has the lines you indicate. Otherwise, `* * * * * zsh -c "export ...`

Comment: @fedorqui , do you mean we cant have multiple cron jobs having different email id ?

Comment: Of course you can, @sashidar, but not the way you are writing it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm mostly working on RHEL 5 and 6 right now - my RH6 box has cronie 1.4 installed.

I am able to put multiple MAILTO lines in the crontab.  The crontab is processed from top to bottom and the MAILTO can be changed in between different jobs.  I think this makes the file very readable and understandable.

So I would write your example code like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
MAILTO="email1@"
0,30 * * * * <cron job>

MAILTO="email2@"
0 1 * * *  find /home/y/logs/ -daystart -type f -ctime +7 -print -exec rm -rf \{\} \;
```

Comment: tested right now on **CentOS 7**: still works as a charm, exactly as described. Thank you!